# Can't access MongoDB cluster after primary node fails

Tags: mongodb

I have an unusual problem. I have configured a 3 node replica set using MongoDB Community edition version 3.6.2, with SSL and Basic-Auth. I can connect to the cluster when the PRIMARY node is the node that I ran rs.initiate() on.

Node1 = Initial node where I ran rs.initiate() and added in additional replicas.

Node2 = Secondary

Node3 = Secondary

All nodes in the replica set have a priority of 10 and votes of 1.

If I then stop Node1 when it is the PRIMARY, I can see one of the other nodes switching to be a PRIMARY, currently Node3 on my servers, but I cannot connect to the cluster after that. Even though there is a primary node available.

In fact the only connection I can make is a direct connection to that node that became the PRIMARY. The normal clustered connection string won't work at all. Once I'm connected onto that node I can run an rs.status() and can see both nodes are currently available, Node3 as primary, Node2 as secondary and Node1 is unreachable.

I'm just wondering if anyone has some idea about what could possibly be wrong here.

I'm using the standard connection string format for a cluster

```
mongodb://user:password@node1:27017,node2:27017,node3:27017/dbName??maxIdleTimeMS=60000&readPreference=primary&ssl=true
```

Comment: Your connection string appears to be missing the [`replicaSet` name](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-option) which is required to establish a replica set connection. If a `replicaSet` name is not provided, your client will create a standalone connection to the first member of your seed list. Standalone connections do not support server discovery or failover.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but nope that did not help either.

Comment: What tool or driver (and version) are you using to connect to MongoDB? What happens with the change of primary? A driver/client using a replica set connection should detect the failover and automatically discover the current primary, but there may be a retry or brief interval where no primary is available (eg. during an election). Can you update with an example of your new connection string with the replica set name included?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out eventually. There were two things in play here.

1. Was to do with the fact the cluster was connecting public DNS names, when a node in the cluster failed, it ignores the nodes on the connection string and attempts to connect to a node using the DNS name it was registered with in the cluster. Those registration are inside a private subnet, so not publicly accessibl and there for could not be seen by the external clients.
   When I was setting up the cluster I had put a registration in my hosts file, to point to the initial node in the cluster using it's public ip address. That is why it could reconnect if one of the other nodes failed and the primary node was available and nominated as the master.
2. I needed to put both the public and private DNS names into the digital certificates I created for each node in the cluster. I put the public DNS as a Subject Alternative Name in the certificate.

Anyway two takeaways for this for me

1. MongoDB only uses the connection string for it's initial connection and settings, after that in a cluster it ignores the connection string and uses the internal cluster registrations for access the nodes.
2. Make a note of all the bloody things I do (like change my private host file) when doing things like this going forward. If I had of remember that it would have made my life simpler.

Cheers
...